# Erro ao atribuir valor a propriedade de struct em C++

Tags: c++, struct

Estou aprendendo a programar e, no momento, tentando fazer um joguinho igual ao popular snake. Falta incrementar várias coisas no programa, como por exemplo os limites das paredes, as colisoes, etc... Então o código a seguir é um esboço do jogo apenas para verificar se a snake consegue se movimentar na tela e aumentar de tamanho ao comer a fruta. O código:

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<vector>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define LIN 20
#define COL 80
using namespace std;
int tela[LIN][COL];
void printtela(){
    int i, j;
    for(i=0;i<LIN;i++){
    for(j=0;j<COL;j++){
        switch(tela[i][j]){
            case 0:
                printf(" ");
                break;
            case 1:
                printf("O");
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("X");
                break;
            }
        }
    printf("\n");
    }
}
vector<int> cobra; 
struct coord {
    int x;
    int y;
};
coord pedaco[800];
pedaco[0].x=1;
pedaco[0].y=1;
cobra.push_back(pedaco[0]);
int main (){
     char com;
     int headx=0, heady=0, fruitx, fruity, i, j;
     bool endgame=0;
     fruitx=rand()%19;
     fruity=rand()%79;
     tela[fruitx][fruity]=2;
     while (!endgame){
         com = getch();
         printf("\e[H\e[2J"); //limpa tela
         switch(com){
        case 'w':
            heady--;
            break;
        case 'a':
            headx--;
            break;
        case 's':
            heady++;
            break;
        case 'd':
            headx++;
            break;
        }
    if (cobra.size()>1){
        for(i=cobra.size();i>0;i--){
            pedaco[i].x=pedaco[i-1].x;
            pedaco[i].y=pedaco[i-1].y;
        }
        pedaco[0].x=headx;
        pedaco[0].y=heady;
    }
    else {
        pedaco[0].x=headx;
        pedaco[0].y=heady;
    }
    for(i=0;i<cobra.size();i++){
        tela[pedaco[i].x][pedaco[i].y]=1;
    }
    printtela();
    }
 return 0;     
}
```

Ao compilar, aparece erro nas linhas 34, 35, 36

> coord pedaco[800];
>       pedaco[0].x=1;
>      pedaco[0].y=1;

error 'pedaco' does not name a type
error 'cobra' does not name a type
O que posso fazer para corrigir isso? Obrigado desde já pelo apoio e atenção.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo o que imagino, você não consegue atribuir nenhum valor em variáveis fora de um contexto de uma função.

Acredito que passando o bloco de código...

```
coord pedaco[800];
pedaco[0].x=1;
pedaco[0].y=1;
cobra.push_back(pedaco[0]);
```

...para dentro a sua função **main** resolva seu problema